# Closing Bluetooth socket

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I've created a socket and connect to a device. This socket is needed in several activites. When I close the app (eg. remove from the drawer) it is impossible to reconnect to the device. I didn't close the connection and socket which is definitely bad and I think it can cause the problem. But I don't know when I should close this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your socket in a separated service (better in foreground) and let your activities exchange data with the service. In this way the socket is kept open as long as your service is on. You can add a "close" button to the notification to shutdown your service and close your socket for example.

Comment: Won't it slow down the app? The socket is used to exchange many messages in a second.

Comment: No, it won't. The socket can't be kept in a Singleton or in every activity. You need to keep a reference to it in a not ui component, i.e. a service